# Constructor of C++ Template with unique_ptr as member fails

Tags: c++

When a class template contains an unique_ptr to another class the constructor of the class does not move the unique_ptr into the new Object.
Using the same class, but without a template the constructor generates the object as expected.

```
#include <iostream>
class test1{
public:
    std::string s_;
    test1(std::string s):s_(s){};
};
class testu{
public:
    std::unique_ptr<test1> us_;
    testu(std::unique_ptr<test1> us):us_(std::move(us)){};
};

template <int i>
class testt {
public:
    std::unique_ptr<test1> us_;
    testt<i>(std::unique_ptr<test1> us):us_(std::move(us)){};
};

template class testt<0>;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    //without template
    std::unique_ptr<test1> us(new test1("test"));
    testu* t1=new testu(move(us));
    std::cout<<t1->us_->s_<<"\n";

    //with template the constructor fails!
    std::unique_ptr<test1> ust(new test1("test"));
    testt<0>* t2=new testt<0>(std::move(us));
    std::cout<<t2->us_->s_<<"\n";  //crash!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Typo? Shouldn't it be `std::move(ust)` in the second paragraph?

Comment: please add std:: in front of move in line `testu* t1=new testu(move(us));`, and please include <memory> and <utility> - compiler does not have to have them in <iostream> header, so It will not compile with every compiler.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't see the problem for hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a typo:

```
testt<0>* t2 = new testt<0>(std::move(us));
```

This line should be

```
testt<0>* t2 = new testt<0>(std::move(ust));
```

`us` was already moved from in the first section of `main`, therefore the access in the penultimate line is invalid:

```
std::cout<<t2->us_->s_<<"\n"; 
//             ^^^
//              | Was already moved from, access causes UB
```

Fixing that makes the [**program run fine**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/170216c102fd3108).